# why Spring boot AspectJ missed to trigger sometimes only

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, aspectj, spring-aspects

I have Spring boot application *AspectJ* is configured to work *async* after one service returned data **but this fails to triggers sometime only** there is no error logs no warning, can this happen any time, please let me know if I have missed any conf?

Application code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
public class TitlesCompareUtilityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TitlesCompareUtilityApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Aspect code

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DistributedLoggingAspect {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DistributedLoggingAspect.class);

    @Async
    @AfterReturning("execution(* com.mycomp.repo.TyRepository.findById(..))")
    public void logAfterReturn(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        int id = (int) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        log.info("logAfterReturn() is running! id:{}", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked as exepected on my local verification. How did you confirm that the aspect fails to trigger at times ? Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As I have mentioned it happens very rarely I am not able to reproduce it

Comment: and how did you confirm that the aspect fails to trigger at times ? `@Around` advice type gives more control and can help you debug

Comment: I didn't see the log of aspect  *logAfterReturn* but in service was executed successfully,

Comment: As long as it cannot be reproduced at will on a different machine and no proof attached to show the aspect missed to advice , it will be hard to comment on what could have happened. If you have a reproducible test case , you can report it as a bug to spring team.

Answer (score 2):

For technical reasons I find it highly unlikely, even next to impossible, that advice execution would sometimes be missed because when a public Spring bean/component method is called and an AOP proxy exists, this proxy will intercept the method call, unless you perform self-invocation (class-internal method call). Whether the advice is executed in the same or an asynchronous thread (if that is even possible), should not matter.

Instead, it is much more likely that due to the asynchronous nature of your application the log entries do not appear in the order you expect or that in a high-load scenario your logger buffer overruns (depending on your configuration) and log messages get lost before they can be written.

Comment: I have search in the entire log file and didnt found the logs, I think the second reason you have mentioned could be possible, huge log is generated I will check for logger buffer setting it is default config as of now

Comment: That is the problem of a missing full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): People - me included - have to speculate. That means, they could be wrong. Maybe I am, maybe not.